# Dynamically created content won't display when running against android 2.1 or lower

Tags: android, view, tablelayout

I'm new to Android application development and i'm trying to create screen full of small buttons. For the purpose i have created TableLayout class where i overwrite onSizeChanged method with following code:

```
    @Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    if(mRows == null && mButtons == null){

        Integer height = new Integer(mActivity.getString(R.string.buttonHeight));
        Integer width = new Integer(mActivity.getString(R.string.buttonWidth));

        mColumnCount = h / height.intValue();
        mRowCount = w / width.intValue();   

        mRows = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
        mButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
        int buttonID = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < mColumnCount ; i++) { 

            mRows.add(new TableRow(mActivity));
            mRows.get(i).setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            addView(mRows.get(i));

            for(int j = 0; j < mRowCount; j++){

                mButtons.add(new Button(mActivity)); 
                mButtons.get(buttonID).setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(width.intValue(), height.intValue()));
                mButtons.get(buttonID).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_normal);
                mButtons.get(buttonID).setClickable(true);
                mButtons.get(buttonID).setSelected(false);
                mButtons.get(buttonID).setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                mButtons.get(buttonID).setOnClickListener(this);
                mButtons.get(buttonID).setId(buttonID);
                mRows.get(i).addView(mButtons.get(buttonID));
                buttonID++;
            }
        }
    defineBorders(); 
    }   
}
```

Now the code works fine when runnings against android 2.2 or higher but i'll get blank screen when i run it against android 2.1 or lower. I don't have any components that requires android 2.2 in order to execute. Actually all the components are pretty much API level 1 stuff.

Besides the code works fine also on 2.1, if the layout is created before it's passed as a parameter on Activity.setContentView(). But i need screen size parameter to make the layout adapt on different screen sizes and based on my understanding i can only get it from view.onSizeChanged method.

Also, when i search the call stack. it shows following sequence on android 2.1 when framework calls view.onSizeChanged:

onSizeChanged(),
onLayout()

When as the sequence on android 2.2 is:

onSizeChanged(),
onLayout(),
onMeasure(),
onLayout()

Is this possibly framework view defect? Or is the view framework changed after 2.1? Any suggestions on course of action?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I can propose u some solutions:

1. Override onDraw() and invoke requestLayout() there to update the dynamic content
2. (Better solution) Use the following:

> 

```
myCustomTableLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Size of your table is known here
            myCustomTableLayout.addDynamicalContent(
                myCustomTableLayout.getWidth(), myCustomTableLayout.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

I didn't try but I believe u can invoke post() method inside onSizeChanged()

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing a reason why you don't create your layouts in xml, for each screen size/density you expect to support as per [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)? You can then let Android handle selecting the appropriate layout and drawing it correctly.

EDIT:

Not certain why it doesn't draw properly on 2.1, however, I would do the initialisation of `mRows` and `mButtons` a little differently (immediately after `super.onSizeChanged` and before your `if`) :

```
if ( mRows == null ) {
    mRows = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
}
if ( mButtons == null ) {
    mButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
}
```

I'd then remove the following `if` and it's accompanying `}`:

```
 if(mRows == null && mButtons == null){
```

My reason for saying this is that if, for whatever reason, one of `mRows` or `mButtons` is non-null, then your drawing code will never be called with your current `if` statement. Do you explicitly initialise them to null?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Thought of letting framework handle the scaling never even crossed my mind. :) According to article, the method sounds very convenient and i shall try it. But the little geek inside me still would like to know the reason why my current implementation works only android 2.2 and above :)

Comment: In a sense you are right but if i would make the changes according your suggestions, the code would end up adding new buttons and rows in tablelayout every time onSizeChanged is called. However, the code pretty raw sketch and it's sole purpose is only for me to get aquianted to the platform.

Comment: and yes, i do explicitly initialise mRows and mButtons as null when intruducing them.